# Subsetting consecutive pairs of rows meeting string conditions

Tags: r

I have a data frame with a 3 columns and several hundred rows. A particular column contains one of three strings: "Open","Close","Cancel"

```
    type    unique_id   group
1   Open    11468329881 g_2
2   Close   11468329881 g_2
3   Open    23254429881 g_3
4   Cancel  23254429881 g_3
5   Open    32550829881 g_4
6   Close   32550829881 g_4
7   Open    43254429881 g_5
8   Close   43254429881 g_5
9   Open    52627629881 g_6
10  Close   52627629881 g_6
11  Open    62747029881 g_7
12  Close   62747029881 g_7
13  Open    2499619881  g_8
14  Close   2499619881  g_8
15  Open    32975019881 g_9
16  Close   32975019881 g_9
17  Open    42975119881 g_10
18  Cancel  42975119881 g_10
19  Open    53560019881 g_11
20  Open    53560019881 g_11
21  Open    62521619881 g_12
22  Close   62521619881 g_12
23  Open    72663719881 g_13
24  Close   72663719881 g_13
25  Open    82663819881 g_14
26  Close   82663819881 g_14
27  Open    92747019881 g_15
28  Open    92747019881 g_15
29  Open    1499629881  g_15
30  Close   1499629881  g_15
```

I would like to loop through each group (ex: `g_1`,`g_2`) and subset the rows if the order is either "Open" "Close" or "Open" "Cancel" any other order should be ignored.

for example g_2 should subset

```
    type    unique_id   group
1   Open    11468329881 g_2
2   Close   11468329881 g_2
```

and `g_11` should be ignored since the order is "Open" "Open"

`g_15` should subset

```
    type    unique_id   group
29  Open    1499629881  g_15
30  Close   1499629881  g_15
```

Any help would be appreciated.

**Edit: I apologize if I wasn't clear earlier. The solution proposed is not working for g_8 for the sample given below**

```
Open    21921312463 g_1
Close   21921312463 g_1
Open    31032312463 g_2
Close   31032312463 g_2
Open    41032212463 g_3
Close   41032212463 g_3
Open    51032312463 g_4
Close   51032312463 g_4
Open    61032212463 g_5
Close   61032212463 g_5
Open    71032312463 g_6
Close   71032312463 g_6
Open    81032212463 g_7
Close   81032212463 g_7
Open    21921312463 g_8
Open    21921312463 g_8
Close   21921312463 g_8
Open    31032312463 g_9
Close   31032312463 g_9
Open    41032212463 g_10
Close   41032212463 g_10
Open    51032312463 g_11
Close   51032312463 g_11
Open    61032212463 g_12
Close   61032212463 g_12
Open    71032312463 g_13
Close   71032312463 g_13
Open    81032212463 g_14
Close   81032212463 g_14
```

I'd like g_8 to be filtered to give

```
Open    21921312463 g_8
Close   21921312463 g_8
```

and ignore the first row in the group

Comment: What role does the `unique_id` play in this? Could there be cases where one `group` includes both `Open` and `Close/Cancel` rows but with different `unique_id`? If so, should these situations be included or thrown out?

Comment: @zx8754 `g_15` contains two different ids, though. But I guess there won't be an ID without a `Open` row, so this is probably redundant.

Comment: I think then, solution should be based on grouping on group and id.

Comment: Yeah, that was my thinking.

Comment: @jonnyblue8 Could yo ushow the expected output

Comment: @akrun Thanks for the quick solution but I'd like to filter pairs of "Open" followed by "Close" or "Cancel" while maintaining the order of the rows. g_8 should extract the second and third row and Ignore the first since it's and "Open" followed by another "Open"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After grouping by 'group', `filter` the rows by checking if `all` the elements in `vector` (`c("Open", "Close")`) or `|` in the other vector (`c("Open", "Cancel")`) are present `%in%` the 'type' column

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  #group_by(group, unique_id) %>%
  filter(all(c("Open", "Close") %in% type)| all(c("Open", "Cancel") %in% type))
```

If the grouping variable includes 'unique_id', update the `group_by` line with `group_by(group, unique_id)`

#### Update

Based on the updated dataset and the new logic, we check the next value to see if it is 'Close' or 'Cancel'

```
df2 %>% 
  group_by(group, unique_id) %>%
   mutate(ind = which(type == "Open" & lead(type) %in% c("Close", "Cancel"))[1]) %>% 
   filter(!is.na(ind)) %>% 
   slice(ind[1]:(ind[1]+1)) %>% 
   select(-ind)
```